# Accessing query set object in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have two models, named as `Human` and `Animal`. The primary key of Human is foreign key in the Animal model. Both has 3 columns each. Human model has c, e, r columns. Animal model has l, i, p columns. I am running a django query on Human model, like this.

```
result = Human.objects.filter().order_by('r')
```

`result` is an queryset object. This object is sent from my view file to a django template page. Inside template page I am looping through `result` and displaying the column values.

Now what i want to do is, I want to also fetch value of `p` column(which is present in the Animal model) inside the same loop, inside that django template. How can we do it in the django template page.

In the python file I can do like this

```
for i in result:
    print i.animal_set.values()[0]['p']
```

But I want to do it in the template page.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
{% for record in result %}
    {{record.c}}, {{record.e}}, 
    {% for animal in record.animal_set|slice:":1" %}
        {{animal.p}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Aamir for your quick reply. I want to display/access 2 columns of Human table and 1 column from Animal table. I can easily get the 2 columns of Human table by doing record.c, But how can I fetch/pull all 3(2 columns from 1st table and 1 column from the 2nd table) in the above code you have provided

Comment: but animals are multiple or you just want the first animal value?

Comment: Updated the answer, in my example i am fetching `c`, `e` from first Human table and column `p` from animal table. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Human and Animals model are in a one-to-many relationship. In Animal table it can have multiple records for 1 Human Id. But as I am querying on the Human model, so I need the 0th index record of Animal model. If the Human model has 3 records and Animal model has 7 records, then I need to display 3 records only

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I'd like to mention that something seems wrong with your database schema. If "c", "e", "r" and others are the real names of the columns - consider renaming them. Second, in the example Python code you have presented, IndexErrors are not caught. If you want to get the first Animal related to the Human object, it would be good to create a getter method in the Human model:

```
def get_first_animal(self):
  try:
    return self.animal_set[0]
  except IndexError:
    return None
```

If you need to show all animals from the template, you can try something like this:

```
{% for animal in human.animal_set.all %}
{{ animal }}
{% endfor %}
```

The variable names given are different, but in your case it would be good to re-factor the code.

Comment: :).. no no, "c", "e", "r" are not real column names.