# Display query set object in django template

Tags: django

I have a model `Post` that I'm trying to display all the posts onto a template. I'm including the post.html onto the home.html....
I found a similar problem to my question but the objects still are not getting displayed [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321515/accessing-query-set-object-in-django-template)

I firt tried the to use python manage.py shell to create an object. So first I did this. 
`Post.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Post: test>, <Post: admin>]>`

then I tried to create a new posts.
`Post.objects.create(user="test", content="New comment")`
but got this error:
`ValueError: Cannot assign "'test'": "Post.user" must be a "User" instance.`

Tried to troubleshoot and couldn't resolve it. So I just decided to write the code in the posts/views.py and it didn't work as well. I figure this is the root of my problem why the objects aren't showing up in the templates.

This is my posts/posts.views

---

```
def posts_list(request):
    # if request.user.is_authenticated():
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "user": "username"
    }
    return render(request, "posts.html", context)
```

---

This is my templates/post.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <h1>What's on your mind, {{ user }}</h1>
    { % for obj in object_list %}
    {{obj.user}}<br/>
    {{obj.content}}<br/>
    {{obj.timestamp}}<br/>
    {% endfor %}

  </body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: user instance means `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` model instance, "test" are just a string, this is not user instance.

Comment: So how do I add a post for a user that's already in the database? Still somewhat confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have asked two questions here. I'll answer both of them below:

**Displaying your posts**

First, you need to make sure that you are passing a user object to your template. Assuming that user info is stored in request.user, you can do so as follows:

views.py:

```
def posts_list(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        user = request.user
        queryset = Post.objects.all()

        context = {
            "object_list": queryset,
            "user": user
        }

        return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

home.html:

```
<html>
<h1>Homepage</h1>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<h1>What's on your mind, {{ user }}</h1>
    { % for obj in object_list %}
    {{obj.user}}<br/>
    {{obj.content}}<br/>
    {{obj.timestamp}}<br/>
    {% endfor %}
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
{% endif %}
</html>
```

**Adding a post for a user**

You need to get a user object to pass to your creation method, rather than using the string "test". The reason your attempt is failing is because you are passing the function a string ("test") where it is expecting a user object.

This line gets a user (arbitrarily grabs the first one in your list):

```
u = User.objects.all()[0]
```

This line imports the datetime module, which you'll need to generate date and datetime objects for your create method:

```
import datetime
```

And this line creates a post for that user:

```
Post.objects.create(user=u, content="New comment", publish=datetime.date.today(), updated=datetime.datetime.now(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: Yeah I realised I was asking two question, thank you. What you consider for my first problem is to remove the template/posts.html and do not include inside of templates/home.html?

Comment: That's part of it — passing parameters in an include isn't trivial, so I've simplified things for now by combining all into one template. The other big problem was that you were passing "username" as a string, rather than an actual user object, to your template in views.py.

Comment: Any particular reason why?

Comment: Ok I understand you,but it's obvious I'm still doing something wrong. I first do this `u = Post.objects.all()[0]` `u = <Post: test>`. Then `Post.objects.create(user=u, content="New comment")` but i get the error `ValueError: Cannot assign "<Post: test>": "Post.user" must be a "User" instance.`

Comment: If I use `u = User.objects.all()[0]` I get `NameError: name 'User' is not defined`

Comment: I'm really new to this, so sorry for the spam of questions.

Comment: One of the reasons to separate the templates in my opinion make the code more modular. I'm essentially making a homepage similar to facebook that have a list of posts

Comment: You want to set u to be a user. Check what model is referenced in your settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL variable, then import that model and try it. For example: if settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL references a model called 'users.User', then try the following in shell: `from users.models import User`, then `u = User.objects.all()[0]`.

Comment: I'd recommend that you keep the templates in one file for now until you figure out the basics. Once you have things working, post a separate question asking how to separate the templates. I'm happy to help with it, but deal with one issue at a time.

Comment: Ok  for now, I'll keep it separate as I'm new to django. After doing what you said with `from users.models import User` `u = <User: test>`. I create the object `Post.objects.create(user=u, content="New comment")` and then I get this error
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_post.publish`

Comment: Would it be much easier if you started a chat and we could possibly talk there?

Comment: You are getting this error because you did not provide a "publish" date, which is a required field in your Post model. I'd recommend that you change `auto_now_add` to `True` on your `publish`, `updated`, and `timestamp` fields. That will make it so that these all default to the current time when you add a new record to the database. Be sure to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` afterwards to commit the migrations to your database.

Comment: I also just updated the query in my answer above to include the required `publish` field.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in request, `django` automatically add requested user. If that user has related permission to add new Post then following code should work

```
Post.objects.create(user=request.user, content="New comment")
```

Comment: Interesting. I still don't understand how it differentiates who's making the post tho. How does it know if its test or admin? Also why doesn't it display on the templates/posts.html

Comment: That doesn't work. I get `NameError: name 'request' is not defined`

Comment: do you add your essential middlewares [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/) you need to make sure you properly add ` `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` middleware.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a foreign key, you are referring a model. 
suppose there are two models A and B. B has following fields - x, y, z. Now, x field is a foreign key, which is referring model A.

Now whenever you want to create an object of B, then the value of x field should be an object of A. Little bit like this -

post1 = Post(user = an object of User Model, content = "your value")

so create an object of User first. Then write it there. otherwise it will give error.

Comment: Ok in the shell I did. `from posts.models import Post`  `from users.models import User`. Then `u = User.objects.all()[0]` `post0 = Post(user=u,content="test data")` `Post.objects.create(post0)` but get an error `create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. I also think when I fix this, I will then get this error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_post.publish`